# The well-defined dimension of a tf.tensor is inexplicably `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, data-wrangling

The example below is extracted from [the official TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) on data pipelines. Basically, one resizes a bunch of JPGs to be `(128, 128, 3)`. For some reason, when applying the `map()` operation, the colour dimension, namely 3, is turned into a `None` when examining the shape of the dataset. Why is that third dimension singled out? (I checked to see if there were any images that weren't `(128, 128, 3)` but didn't fid any.)

If anything, `None` should only show up for the very first dimension, i.e., that which counts the number of examples, and should not affect the individual dimensions of the examples, since---as nested structures---they're supposed to have the same shape anyway so as to be stored as `tf.data.Dataset`s.

The code in TensorFlow 2.1 is

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf

# Download the files.
flowers_root = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)
flowers_root = pathlib.Path(flowers_root)

# Compile the list of files.
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(flowers_root/'*/*'))

# Reshape the images.
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def parse_image(filename):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '\\') # Use the forward slash on Linux
  label = parts[-2]

  image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
  print("Image shape:", image.shape)
  return image, label

print("Map the parse_image() on the first image only:")
file_path = next(iter(list_ds))
image, label = parse_image(file_path)

print("Map the parse_image() on the whole dataset:")
images_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image)
```

and yields

```
Map the parse_image() on the first image only:
Image shape: (128, 128, 3)
Map the parse_image() on the whole dataset:
Image shape: (128, 128, None)
```

Why `None` in that last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tutorial you are missing this part

```
for image, label in images_ds.take(5):
    show(image, label)
```

The line

```
images_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image)
```

only creates a placeholder
and there is no image being passed to the function
if you put prints the file_path is blank
But if your use

```
for image, label in images_ds.take(5)
```

it iterates over each image passing it through the parse_image function.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that `.map()` would execute eagerly as that would presumably be the default behavior with TensorFlow 2.0. It seems, however, that's not the case, and the "eagerness" is only triggered by `.take()`?

Comment: the map function creates a graph of the function parse Image. when you run it through map tensorflow executes the graph.